# Tkinter autoreload function spawns new loop each time it's called

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that pulls and displays several updating values. I have a button that manually reloads the necessary information. My end goal is to have a text field where I can type in a value, and have the program reload every `x` seconds. My issue arises in setting the new loop interval value.

The following is a basic example of the issue I'm having:

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        reloadTimer=tk.Entry(root)
        reloadTimer.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        reloadTimer.insert(10,10)

        def masterReload():
            print("LOADING " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            parent.after(int(reloadTimer.get())*1000, masterReload)

        masterReloadButton = tk.Button(root, text='Set', command=lambda:masterReload())
        masterReloadButton.pack()

        masterReload()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

My issue is that everytime I press the `masterReloadButton`, a new "reload-loop" is started.

For example:

This is the output before I press any buttons. Loop intervals are ~10 seconds apart.

[image: Properly working Loop, ~10 seconds intervals]

This is the output after I press my `masterReloadButton`, roughly 5 seconds into the loop. There are now two loops occurring concurrently, with about a 5 second offset. It *does* grab the new loop value, but it also spawns a new loop entirely.

[image: Concurrent loops: unwanted result]

---

I need the "set" button because otherwise the new timer value is only retrieved upon a reload. If someone enters a very large number, it would take a very long amount of time before the program would accept a new value.

To me, it seems like a new `masterReload()` process is created every time I hit my button. I need to either destroy the process each time, or reorganize my code so that it doesn't happen, but I'm unsure of how to do either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @stovfl I don't understand, could you clarify exactly what I should be disabling, and how I should go about doing it?

Comment: @stovfl I still want to be able to click the button and grab new values after the program has started.

Comment: @stovfl Yes, but I want to be able to inject new interval values. If someone enters 100000, they must wait 100000 seconds before being able to enter a different value. I want the button to be able to force a new interval, but I don't know how to do that without re-calling the function itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prevent the issue you are seeing is to disable the button after its been pressed.

We can start the `master_reload` loop and disable the button at the same time with a `lambda` expression.

Here is your code cleaned up a little with the button set to disabled after first press.

Update: Now updates after loop right away instead of waiting for last loop to finish.

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime


class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.reload_timer = tk.Entry(self)
        self.reload_timer.pack(side='left')
        self.reload_timer.insert(10, 10)
        self.active_after = None
        self.time_tracker = None
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text='Set', command=self.set_time_tracker)
        self.btn.pack()

    def master_reload(self):
        print("LOADING {}".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
        self.active_after = self.after(self.time_tracker*1000, self.master_reload)

    def set_time_tracker(self):
        x = self.reload_timer.get()
        if x.isdigit():
            if int(x) > 0:
                if self.active_after is not None:
                    self.after_cancel(self.active_after)
                    self.active_after = None
                    self.time_tracker = int(x)
                    self.master_reload()
                else:
                    self.time_tracker = int(x)
                    self.master_reload()
            else:
                self.after_cancel(self.active_after)
                self.active_after = None
        else:
            if self.active_after is not None:
                self.after_cancel(self.active_after)
                self.active_after = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApplication().mainloop()
```

The benefit here is you can change the time any time you want without causing duplicate loops and even stop the loop by typing a zero `0` or any letters and pressing set.

Comment: Thank you Mike, the second bit of code is exactly what I was looking for - being able to edit the interval at any point. +1

Comment: @EmilioGarcia I am getting ready to add a method to the class that will let you cancel the existing after timer so you do not need to wait for it to elapse before new timer is set.

Comment: When I first tested your code I thought I was able to do that. Hmm. (When I first tested, the timer value was reprinted in the console, but I don't see it now, or in your posts edit history. I readded print(x) for testing). 

However, now when I retest, I seem to be coming across the same issue I had initially, where after re-setting the timer variable, a double loop starts. See here: https://i.imgur.com/6wUcsIb.png

Comment: I have updated my code so it will update the after loop right away.

Comment: The new code seems to work perfectly. I've re-marked as resolved. Thank you again.

Comment: @EmilioGarcia happy to help. Sometimes it takes a little more effort for something that seams like it should be simple.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**:  I want the button to be able to force a new interval

The *new interval* is computed using

```
int(reloadTimer.get())*1000
```

therefore no `Button` click are required.

---

To force a new interval, you have to **cancel** the current running `reload_after()` loop and start a new one.

Use, two functions, `masterReload()`, **cancel/start** `reload_after()` on `Button` click.
The other, `reload_after()`, shows the values by looping.

> **Cancel `.after(...`** on `Button` click:

```
    self.after_id = None

    def masterReload():
        # New intervall

        # Cancel previous reload_after() loop
        if self.after_id:
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
            self.after_id = None

        # Start new reload_after() loop
        parent.after(0, reload_after)

    def reload_after():
        print("LOADING " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        self.after_id = parent.after(int(reloadTimer.get())*1000, reload_after)

    masterReloadButton = tk.Button(root, text='Set', command=lambda:masterReload())
```

Comment: `lambda:masterReload()` is overkill. Best to change that to `masterReload`